# MPI and OpenMP on Desktop CPUs

Tags: mpi, openmp

I was just wondering how is it possible that OpenMP (shared memory) and MPI (distributed memory) could run on normal desktop CPUs like i7 for example. Is there some kind of a virtual machine that can simulate shared and distributed memory on these CPUs? I am asking it because when learnig OpenMP and MPI, the structures of supercomputers is shown, with shared memory or different nodes for distributed memory, each node with its own processor and memory.

Comment: MPI is not just for distributed memory systems but it is useful for these such systems. you can use in both systems. MPI just creates a communication between processes that these processes can be anywhere (on a desktop computer or on a cluster)

Comment: MPI is a bit of an overkill to use on a shared memory system, but yes, it works. It's called portability :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MPI assumes nothing about how and where MPI processes run. As far as MPI is concerned, processes are just entites that have a unique address known as their *rank* and MPI gives them the ability to send and receive data in the form of *messages*. How exactly are the messages transfered is left to the implementation. The model is so general that MPI can run virtually on any platform imaginable.

OpenMP deals with shared memory programming using *threads*. Threads are just concurrent instruction flows that can access a shared memory space. They can execute in a timesharing fashion on a single CPU core or they can execute on multiple cores inside a single CPU chip, or they can be distributed among multiple CPUs connected together by some sophisticated network that allows them to access each others memory.

Given all that, MPI does not require that each process executes on a dedicated CPU core or that millions of cores should be necessarily put on separate boards connected with some high speed network - performance does, as well as technical limitations. You can happily run a 100 processes MPI job on a single CPU core though performance would be *very very bad* but it will still work (given enough memory is available). The same applies to OpenMP - it does not require that each thread is scheduled on a dedicated CPU core but doing so gives the best performance.

That's why MPI and OpenMP are called *abstractions* - they are general enough that the execution hardware can vary greatly while source code is kept the same.

Comment: Thank you guys, I think the right word was "abstraction". I think we can go further and say that a shared machine could simulate a distributed machine and that a distributed machine could simulate a shared memory machine. That way, shared, distributed, MPI and OpenMP are just concepts or abstractions.

Comment: Indeed, here at RWTH we have a large ScaleMP system that builds a shared memory virtual machine on top of multiple cluster nodes and happily runs OpenMP. And Intel used to have a slightly more run-time based solution in the form of ClOMP (Cluster OpenMP) but the project appears abandoned nowadays. Distributed memory is implemented trivially on a shared memory machine - just take OS processes with their isolated virtual address spaces.

Answer (score 4):

A modern multicore-CPU-based PC *is* a shared-memory computer.  It is a sensible approximation to think of each core as a processor, and that they all have equal access to the same RAM.  This approximation hides a lot of details of processor and chip architectures.

It has always (well, perhaps not always, but for almost as long as MPI has been around) been possible to use message-passing (of which MPI is one standard) on a shared-memory computer so that you can run the same MPI-enabled program as you would on a genuinely distributed-memory machine.

At the application level a programmer only cares about calls to MPI routines.  At the systems level the MPI run-time translates these calls into, well on a cluster or supercomputer, into instructions to send stuff over the interconnect.  On a shared-memory computer it could instead translate these calls into instructions to send stuff over the internal bus.

This is by no means a comprehensive introduction to the topics you've raised, but that's what Google and all the published sources out there are for.